# limit record set for window lag function to current day

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use the postgresql lag function to pull out the next record for a user but how do i limit that to the day of the current record?

```
SELECT (sd.doc ->> 'readerId'::text)::integer current, LAG((sd.doc ->> 'readerId'::text)::integer) OVER (ORDER BY sd.created_at DESC) next FROM sd
```

There are only 3 fields in the table- id (primary key), doc (jsonb type) and created_at timestamp.

The issue is that i want to pick the next readerId the user visits for that day. with my current query, it could return the next readerId from the next day.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just partition it by day:

```
SELECT (sd.doc ->> 'readerId'::text)::integer current, LAG((sd.doc ->> 'readerId'::text)::integer) OVER (PARTITION BY date_trunc('1 day', sd.created_at) ORDER BY sd.created_at DESC) next FROM sd
```